# mysqlclient-python & security issues

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-connector-python

I can't figure out whether I'll bear any risk in terms of malicious software & security if I download mysqlclient-python from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient? Is mysqlclient-python provided in PyPI reliable in your opinion? I want to install mysqlclient in my global Python environment, not virtualenv.

I've started learning Python. I want to try Django framework and Mysql database. I've already installed them. I know that PyPI is a third party repository, and everyone with a bit of experience can write and upload their package to PyPI.

Is it safe to install mysqlclient, using pip and PyPI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyPI is the official package distribution channel linked from the main page of https://www.python.org.

Having that in mind, you certainly bear all risks by downloading and installing anything from the internet. Not a long time ago, neither `setuptools` nor `pip` could verify SSL certificates and most of communication was over plain HTTP. It's a usual and good practice to test all the software you are going to use in production environment somewhere in an isolated environment, and set up your production environment from an internal repository of packages already tested by you. Any package management software allows specifying a custom repository to install from.

Comment: Thanks. I want pip to install mysqlclient from PyPI. Could you explain how to specify this repository for pip?

Comment: @aspiring, it's the default repository, you do not need to explicitly specify anything.

Comment: Can pip download by default from a repository other than PyPI? Does pip primarily search PyPI for a package that I need?

Comment: @aspiring, there are number of options how you can configure `pip`, and I suggest reading the doc about it: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#finding-packages

Comment: Thanks to your link, I've read the information on modifying how packages are found by pip in various repos.

Comment: @aspiring, nice to hear that, you are welcome. If the question is answered, it's a good habit to mark the answer as accepted.